# list of items added in cart shows when click on bag icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about" onClick="testMy()">CART</a></li>
  
 <div>Empty cart add something</div>
</ul>
```

i'm developing a navigation menu for shopping cart where on right corner side i have created a Link clickable named "CART" so i'm trying to make it like,. when user click on "CART" one div appears with a list of items which he have added into CART and clicking again it will close.

looking for javascript code for that div so div will appear exactly under cart menu link with arrow pointed to cart as showed in image i have attached.

[Item list in cart with arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aund6.png)

Comment: I think this pen can help you: http://codepen.io/drehimself/pen/VvYLmV

Comment: well that one will almost help me thanks but again what i want is responsive div like here http://www.apple.com/ take a look keep cart dropdown open and make browser windows smaller till it go into mobile version so it will move div to left side automatically but arrow sticks to cart icon

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a new, absolute positioned element which is set to the right hand side of the screen (just under the nav) using jQuery you can fade in the element.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="cartButton">CART</li>
</ul>

<div class="cart">
   <div>Empty cart add something</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

li.cartButton {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
   right: 0px;
   padding-top: 10px;
}

li.cartButton.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.active {
  a {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  } 
}

.cart  {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.cartButton').click(function() {
 $('.cartButton').toggleClass('active');
 $('.cart').fadeIn();
})
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x8gujt4/)

Note
You will need to add a condition to fade out the cart element using jquery using the ***fadeToggle*** function instead of ***fadeIn***.

Alternatively, It may suite you better to just add a css class to the cart element so you can assign css transitions.

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x8gujt4/2/) (Updated with cart arrow)

The cart arrow was created with a square div rotated 45 degrees and place underneath the navigation bar by adding a z-index to the nav. By adding the `.cart` class, it will only show when the cart button it clicked.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but does not have arrow and div is going outside of screen maybe i will workout a little bit on that

Comment: @ArchiPatel Just adjust the div position. Make sure to give the arrow the class of .cart.

Comment: I have just updated the example with the cart arrow (Bottom jsFiddle Link).